# show and hide an image onclick

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, show-hide

I have the user profile picture inside a table having 100px for height and width.
I also have radio buttons to set visibility of the profile picture (public, Private, etc.). These are updated using ajax.

What I want to know is how can I show a image (e.g. "success.png") right above the profile picture and fade it out after 2 seconds?

```
<table class="profimg">
<tr><td align="center"><img class="profimg" src="../images/user/profile/1c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b1.jpg" alt="Administratorasdf" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><input type='radio' title='Publicly Visible' name='img_pub' onclick="upimg1()" /> <input type='radio' title='Visible Only To Users' value='UsersOnly' name='img_pub' onclick="upimg2()" /> <input type='radio' title='Visible Only To You' value='Hide' name='img_pub' onclick="upimg3()" checked='checked'/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Plain javascript or is jQuery OK?

Comment: well, I don't know how to do this. so, none.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13358003/1609555)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added an img tag with the ID 'success'. This tag is the image that fades in and out.

```
$("#rad").click(function () {
    $("#success").fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

dont forget to include the jquery library.
Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c7ajb/10/)

Comment: Do you know about jQuery chaining so you only evaluate `$("#success")` one time.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just read up on jquery chaining, and yes the use of chaining would make my code more elegant and faster. Thanks! :)

Comment: @awadm thanks. even if its working on jsfiddle, it ain't running on my website. I have already included these libraries
`<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>`

Comment: Check the console in developer tools in chrome or FF to get an idea what the error is. Check if you set img tag id to 'success'. Its better if you could include the radio buttons inside a div and give the div a unique ID in order to avoid conflicts with other input tags (use this ID instead of 'input' in your jquery). remember to update these in jquery too. Use `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>`

Comment: The custom here is to edit your answer to improve it when people make good suggestions.  Why not add chaining to it?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".profimg").click(function(){
        $("this").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to use jquery library.This will not take 2 seconds. But it'll work. you can use settimeout function for time interval. google for it

Comment: This shows/hides the profimg.  That isn't what the OP asked.  The OP asked to show another image above the profile image.